# How to send different sms messages to multiple recipients

Tags: php, sms

i have a somewhat challenging task.I have to write an application with PHP and MYSQL
This application is intended to be an sms application that sends sms(text messages) to
various job supervisors,reporting the messages that their subordinates have received.
The application is meant to have a template;
E.g :Message From Postmaster:
Message From Auditor:
etc.
The messages for each subordinate are stored in a table and are retrieved
for each subordinate for a given time period.Each subordinate has a job role which defines the kind of message he receives.
That is:A postman has "pre-defined" people that can send a message.E.g The Postmaster,the Post-office....etc.
An example showing the message format is:

```
   Message From Auditor:Bring Receipts To General Office Sent On Monday

   Message From Postmaster:Bring Stamps To Secretariat Sent On Monday

   Message From Security: Bring Details For Id Card Sent On Tuesday

   Message From Admin:

   Message From Supply:
```

Two subordinates with the same job role can have different messages from the same person.
E.g: Employee x who is a postman might receive "Report to General Office" from the Postmaster,
while Employee y might receive the message "Add New Delivery Routes From Next Week"
The phone numbers for the Supervisors are stored in a table.
A supervisor can supervise multiple people
who have different job roles.

The major point where i will need assistance
is on how to program the application to pick the phone number of the supervisor for each
employee,get the templates for the employee's job role,and populate it with the messages
for the employee and send it to the supervisor.Also, the employees can have more than 1 supervisor.
I know i will need a loop(a "for-each" loop ??)..
I am not also very knowledgeable about the procedure used in sending sms messages to people
from a website with php,
but i know it has to do with arrays.
So in short...i need help on building arrays that will house the phone numbers,message-template
and message template for a particular job role with individual messages
and loop through them
and send them to the recipients.
I will really appreciate any help i can get and i will gladly supply my email to interested parties to further correspondence.THANKS

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you looked up SMS gateways? You really don't want to write that yourself, trust me.

Comment: You could start by reading a tutorial (like this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php/) on how to send SMS with PHP. But then you have another problem in your question which belongs to the code for getting the correct recipients - this is rather program logic so you should edit your question to break this down into a single problem. Also you might want to show some research effort. (You could create an object graph in UML or similar and maybe then it gets clearer to you and us, how your Domain objects are connected.)

Comment: There really isn't a specific question here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to learn some more PHP/MySQL before you'll be able to tackle this...  The major part you need help with is straightforward, just some tables and queries...  For the SMS, Google for "PHP SMS API" and you will find scads of options.

> I am not also very knowledgeable about the procedure used in sending
>   sms messages to people from a website with php, but i know it has to
>   do with arrays

No this is not true.  Arrays may be used to implement portions of the code used in doing so, but that statement is like saying building a website w/ PHP has to do w/ arrays...  You might try the [php-general mailing list](http://php.net/mailing-lists.php) for more help getting off the ground in your PHP coding, but there really isn't a specific question here.